# How does resteasy choose its providers from META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers files?

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

In which order does resteasy load the providers from the META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers files of all dependencies?
Is there any documentation or some code at https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy ?